# How to apply built-in footer style using Aspose Word?

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, aspose.words

Recenty I am using Aspose Word to generating some reports, and there is a small problem.

Currently I am using `DocumentBuilder` and a 2-column table to make up the footer, System name at first column align to left while page number at second column align to right.

Everything is fine, yet I do not want the footer looks so dull as plain text, so I would like to add some style to the footer.

I would like to apply some built-in template of footer, say **Alphabet** as shown below, is it possible to do so by using Aspose Word?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MS Word 2013 installed on your machine, you'll most likely find a Word document 'Built-In Building Blocks.dotx' at the following location:

C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx

The predefined built-in building blocks entries that ship with Word are stored in above template document. Using Aspose.Words, you can extract any building block from it and paste inside another Word document.

GlossaryDocument class in Aspose.Words represents such Building Blocks. Please try using the following code:

```
Document docBuildingBlocks = new Document(MyDir + @"Building Blocks.dotx");
Document doc = new Document();

DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary);

GlossaryDocument glossaryDocument = docBuildingBlocks.GlossaryDocument;
foreach (BuildingBlock buildingBlock in glossaryDocument.BuildingBlocks)
{
    if (buildingBlock.Gallery.ToString().StartsWith("Footer") &&
        buildingBlock.Name.Equals("ViewMaster (Vertical)"))
    {
        Section sec = (Section)buildingBlock.FirstChild;
        foreach (Node node in sec.Body.ChildNodes)
        {
            HeaderFooter hf = doc.FirstSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary];
            hf.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(node, true));
        }
    }
}

doc.Save(MyDir + @"15.6.0.docx");
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks, I think it can do the work, yet in my case I cannot be to sure what version of office, or what the path is exactly like on production server, so we cannot access this "Build Blocks.dotx" that easily.  So I just want to be sure, is it the only way to do my job? If yes, though I cannot use it but I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Yes. I think, this is the only way to do this. Secondly, you can copy .dotx containing building blocks from development machine into any accessible directory e.g. where you deployed web app in production environment. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.