# How to align ViewMaster (Vertical) to LEFT side of the page in the word/pdf

Tags: java, .net, aspose, aspose.words

How to align ViewMaster (Vertical) to LEFT side of the page in the word/pdf ?

We have achieved inserting ViewMaster (vertical) in the document by following below link
[How to apply built-in footer style using Aspose Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826078/how-to-apply-built-in-footer-style-using-aspose-word/73275734#73275734)

#aspose.words #aspose

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply change alignment of paragraph in the inserted header using [ParagraphFormat.Alignment](https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/paragraphformat/alignment/). If you insert ViewMaster header as the primary header, you can use code like this to change alignment of paragraphs in it:

```cs
foreach (Paragraph p in doc.FirstSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary].Paragraphs)
    p.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
```

In case of ViewMaster (Vertical) footer, vertical contetn is represented using shape and group shape in footer. So you can use code like this to change position of these shapes:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");

MoveShapesLeft(doc.FirstSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary].GetChildNodes(NodeType.Shape, true));
MoveShapesLeft(doc.FirstSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary].GetChildNodes(NodeType.GroupShape, true));

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

```cs
private static void MoveShapesLeft(NodeCollection shapes)
{
    foreach (ShapeBase shape in shapes)
    {
        if (!shape.IsTopLevel)
            continue;

        shape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = RelativeHorizontalPosition.Margin;
        shape.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Tried the above code, still ViewMaster(vertical) is at Right side of the page. Attached screenshot for more clarity

Comment: `HeaderFooter footerFirst = doc.getFirstSection().getHeadersFooters().getByHeaderFooterType(HeaderFooterType.FOOTER_FIRST);
footerFirst.getParagraphs().forEach((p) ->  p.getParagraphFormat().setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT));`

Comment: I have update my answer. Vertical content is represented using shape and group shape.

Comment: Tried below code is not aligning on left, still view master (vertical) is inserting on right page

`moveShapesLeft(doc.getFirstSection().getHeadersFooters().getByHeaderFooterType(HeaderFooterType.FOOTER_FIRST).getChildNodes(NodeType.SHAPE, true));
                    moveShapesLeft(doc.getFirstSection().getHeadersFooters().getByHeaderFooterType(HeaderFooterType.FOOTER_FIRST).getChildNodes(NodeType.GROUP_SHAPE, true));`

Comment: moveShapesLeft(NodeCollection shapes) {
        for (Object base : shapes) {
            ShapeBase shapeBase = (ShapeBase) base;
            if (shapeBase.isTopLevel()) {
                continue;
            }
            shapeBase.setRelativeHorizontalPosition(RelativeHorizontalPosition.MARGIN);
            shapeBase.setHorizontalAlignment(RelativeHorizontalPosition.MARGIN);
        }
}

Comment: Could you please post the question in Aspose.Words support forum and attach the document there? https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8 I have tested on my side with simple document with ViewMaster (Vertical) footer and it's position is properly changed. As I can see you process FOOTER_FIRST, please make sure the footer is the first footer in your document.

Comment: As suggested posted same in the Aspose support forum.
Ref link
https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-to-align-viewmaster-vertical-to-left-side-of-the-page-in-the-word-pdf/250365

Comment: please refer the working code in Aspose.Words support forum https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-to-align-viewmaster-vertical-to-left-side-of-the-page-in-the-word-pdf/250365