# How to replace date field with some text in the ViewMaster (Vertical) for word/pdf using Aspose?

Tags: java, asp.net, aspose, aspose.words

> Aspose code is inserting Viewmaster(vertical) with default date to
> select as a text inside. I want to replace with some text as shown in
> the image.
>
> Followed the code mentioned in [ViewMaster(vertical) using Aspose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826078/how-to-apply-built-in-footer-style-using-aspose-word?noredirect=1&lq=1)
> to generate the ViewMaster(Vertical) in the word/pdf. can someone help
> in getting the right code to replace the date with text

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date is set in structured document tag. You can use code like this to get and modify value of this SDT:

```cs
// Get structured document tags from footer.
NodeCollection tags = doc.FirstSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary].GetChildNodes(NodeType.StructuredDocumentTag, true);
foreach (StructuredDocumentTag tag in tags)
{
    if (tag.Title.Equals("Date") && tag.SdtType == SdtType.Date)
    {
        tag.IsShowingPlaceholderText = false;
        tag.FullDate = DateTime.Now;
        // By default SDT is minded to XML. We can simply remove mapping to use value set in FullDate property.
        tag.XmlMapping.Delete();
    }
}
```

If you do not need date, but need to insert some custom text, you can remove the tag and insert a simple paragraph with text instead. For example:

```cs
// Get structured document tags from footer.
NodeCollection tags = doc.FirstSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary].GetChildNodes(NodeType.StructuredDocumentTag, true);
foreach (StructuredDocumentTag tag in tags)
{
    if (tag.Title.Equals("Date") && tag.SdtType == SdtType.Date)
    {
        // Put an empty paragraph ater the structured document tag
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(doc);
        tag.ParentNode.InsertAfter(p, tag);
        // Remove tag
        tag.Remove();
        // move DocumentBuilder to the newly inserted paragraph and insert some text.
        builder.MoveTo(p);
        builder.Write("This is my custom vertical text");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your response. Above code works fine and able to insert the given date in the code, but in my case I need to remove the Date set  and place some text inside the viewmaster(vertical)

Comment: thank a ton Alexy Noskov, updated code works